# Unable to connect MongoDB, Connection refused

Tags: mongodb, connection

Suddenly my mongodb stopped working after a forced system restart.

i'm getting message

```
Unable to connect MongoDB, please check your configurations. MongoDB said:Failed to connect to: 127.0.0.1:27017: Connection refused.
```

i tried following this solution available on stackoverflow:

```
Step 1: Remove lock file.
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

Step 2: Repair mongodb.
mongod --repair 

Step 3: start mongodb.
sudo start mongodb 
or
sudo service mongodb start

Step 4: Check status of mongodb.
sudo status mongodb 
or   
sudo service mongodb status

Step 5: Start mongo console.
mongo
```

I'm getting an error in Step 3:

```
start: Unknown job: mongodb
```

[Here's](http://laravel.io/bin/EGnd2) the log file:

Comment: How is mongodb installed? Do you have /etc/init.d/mongod on your system( I assume it is linux)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try following steps.**

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10

echo deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen

sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen

mongod --repair

sudo service mongodb start

mongo
```

**Its working in my system.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mongo 2.6 and this is not working, However I tried the bellow commands and it works fine for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=2.6.1 mongodb-org-server=2.6.1 mongodb-org-shell=2.6.1 mongodb-org-mongos=2.6.1 mongodb-org-tools=2.6.1
```